# Change the value of ID by Class rating css

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code is:

```
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="0" checked /><span id="hide"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" /><span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" /><span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" /><span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /><span></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" /><span></span>
</div>
```

Change id="hide" for class="hide"

I would like to know how I can change the value of ID for a class without affecting the html code generated css

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjpqc661/

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changind the id with class like this:

```
<span id="hide"></span>
```

to:

```
<span class="hide"></span>
```

and by changing in the CSS file the `#hide` into `.hide` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bjpqc661/1/).

Comment: There is an extra star appearing in your fiddle.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use id?